# React Native - AsyncStorage screen update content on load

Tags: react-native

Have looked at others solutions, but they don't seem to be good in my case.

I have a Utilities.js file:

```
const setItem = async (value) => {
  if (!value) return;
  AsyncStorage.setItem('@my_key', value);
};

const getItem = async () => {
  var val = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@my_key');
  return val;
};
```

All the users' input are being saved in the AsyncStorage via code on Screen1:

```
Utilities.setItem('value')
```

Once data is saved we can go to Screen2 to read up the AsyncStorage via the getItem() method put in ComponentDidMount method:

```
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    let asyncValue = await Utilities.getItem();
    let objFromAsyncValue = JSON.parse(asyncValue);
    this.setState({
      storage: objFromAsyncValue
    })
  }
```

All works well if I open Screen2 for the 1st time - all saved data is being shown, but going back and adding additional values for AsyncStorage obj is not being updated on Screen2 - but asyncstorage has more items added.

So far have tried triggering method:

```
this.forceUpdate()
```

and checking if the event onDidFocus has been triggered on load:

```
<NavigationEvents onDidFocus={ alert('Scren refreshed')} />
```

I know component rendering is state based, but in my instance I have no states to be updated, only AsyncStorage stateless object.

How can I refresh the screen and/or just read the updated content of AsyncStorage object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're assuming that Screen2 mounts every time you focus it. This may not be necessarily true. What you should do is move your `getItem` call inside another method and call it `onWillFocus`.

Like this,

```
onFocus = async () => {
    let asyncValue = await Utilities.getItem();
    let objFromAsyncValue = JSON.parse(asyncValue);
    this.setState({
      storage: objFromAsyncValue
    })
}
```

And then,

`<NavigationEvents onDidFocus={ alert('Scren refreshed')} onWillFocus={this.onFocus}/>`

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would use a context, where your provider is the the content the user type and gets saved to the asyncstorage, the consumer would be the screen 2. That way you only need to access the asyncstorage on screen 1 and screen 2 will always be up to date to whatever has been typed and saved on screen 1

See: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html